# Ошибка сборки Firefox 68

Tags: python, debian, python-2.x, firefox, сборка

**Дано:** Debian 10. Пытаюсь собрать из исходников [firefox 68](https://packages.debian.org/sid/firefox). Но при сборке вылетает с ошибкой:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nihi1ist/src/firefox/68.0.1/firefox-68.0.1/configure.py", line 16, in <module>
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(base_dir, 'python', 'mozbuild'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 73, in join
    path += '/' + b
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)
make[2]: *** [debian/rules:236: stamps/configure-browser] Ошибка 1
make[2]: выход из каталога «/home/nihi1ist/src/firefox/68.0.1/firefox-68.0.1»
make[1]: *** [debian/rules:353: build-arch] Ошибка 2
make[1]: выход из каталога «/home/nihi1ist/src/firefox/68.0.1/firefox-68.0.1»
make: *** [debian/rules:353: build] Ошибка 2
```

В питоне не разбираюсь, от слова "совсем". Подскажите как решить проблему сборки?

Comment: в первоначальном варианте вопроса фигурировал каталог, содержащий в имени кириллицу. возможно, это и было проблемой. особенно учитывая что это как раз пятнадцатый (начиная с нуля) байт, и содержит как раз `0xd0`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin aka `'\xd0'`